# Should I use Infura for high volume checking site?

Tags: dapps, ethers.js, infura

Releasing a DAPP soon that uses Infura to read information from my smart contract. There are a lot of calls using Infura on the frontend because I want to keep everything updated. Are there any limits to amount of RPC calls I can do. They say without setting a limit, they use a default, but can't seem to find that cap.

There was about 700 calls on frontend after testing A LOT just by myself for 30 min. Makes sense because I am hitting multiple checks every x amount of seconds. Would rather the user not refresh to see changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted from the [Infura Docs](https://docs.infura.io/infura/networks/ethereum/how-to/avoid-rate-limiting),

> Infura is constantly adjusting rate limits based on overall usage and possible abuse.
> **Typically only aggressive use should experience rate limiting.**

According to another page on the [Infura Docs](https://docs.infura.io/infura/networks/ethereum/how-to/secure-a-project/set-rate-limits), it's possible to set rate limits yourself if you wish to do so.

A quote from [Github Issue #58](https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/58) on the Infura repo: (may be outdated, this was posted in October 2018)

> We do not currently have any rate limits, and will clearly publish them if we implement them. However the production infrastructure is a shared resource, so you may be seeing contention w/ other requests.

Comment: Ahhhh I see, so is there a better way to automatically update the frontend when the contract updates other than calling a read call every X amount of seconds?

Comment: @frankied003 Yes! The web3 subscribe function would be perfect for this. https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-subscribe.html - You can subscribe to a specific event in your smart contract, so the frontend will only make a new call everytime it *knows* the data going to be fetched is updated.